# ASP.net MVC4 validating elements of a drop down in the model?

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

How can I validate the values assigned to elements of a dropdown list?  Normally I would assign ranges in the model and that field would be validated.  However, if I have something like this I am not sure how to handle it.

Model

```
public class Product
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public decimal Value { get; set; }
   public DateTime Given { get; set; }
   public TimeSpan TimeGiven { get; set; }
   public string Phase { get; set; }
   public bool Active { get; set; }
   public int PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

The name in the model is a dropdown list of different products.  I am not sure how to handle the validation for the Value since the different products will have different ranges.  For example, Product Named X will have a valid range of 25-30 where product Y will have a valid range of .01 - .5.  The Person can have many products assigned so I have a one to many relationship set up with Person and Product.

Is there a way to validate the value based on what product they select X, Y?  I will have approximately 40 different products so Ideally I could do this without having to having a separate model for each product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate using custom business rules with a `ValidationAttribute`

It is very straightforward you just need to do the following:

1. Create a class that inherits from `ValidationAttribute` and override the `IsValid` method.
2. Decorate your property with the attribute you just created.

For example:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple =false, Inherited = false)]
public class MyBusinessRuleValidation: ValidationAttribute
{
  protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object v, ValidationContext validationContext)
  {        
    var Name = (string)v //since we decorated the property Name with this attribute;
    //retrieve Value's value using validationContext
    var value = (decimal) validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty("Value").GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

    //check whether you need to exit with error
    if( name == ProductX) { 
      if(value > 10 && value < 25) 
        return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);

    }          

    return ValidationResult.Success;
  }
}
```

Use the validator:

```
public class Product
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [MyBusinessRuleValidation(ErrorMessage="Some ugly error")]      
   public string Name { get; set; }
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Can you give me a little bit more toward the Validation class use?  My question is on the ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ...  Since I am going to need to match on the Name and Value of my Product Model I am not sure how to do this.  Is the value passed there the value the user enters and if I get the "Name" property into a var.  How would I get the name and value into a variable so I could check it like the following: if( name == ProductX) { if(value > 10 && value < 25) return validationresult.success;}  Different range for each name.

Comment: Yes value holds the value in "Name". You get a reference to the prop "Value" through the validationContext. See updated answer.

Comment: Excellent.  It is mostly working now.  How can I handle if the value is an INT?  Some Products have to be Ints but I will store them as decimal values in the DB.  I just need to check they are an INT.  I tried casting int(value) in the case where Name should have a value of int.  That came back with invalid cast exception.  You did answer the original question so if this is a different question that is cool.

Comment: You can use Int32.TryParse on "Value" to test whether you are getting what you want.